# Outs when needing more than one card

Tags: probability

I recently learnt about outs, and the magic 4-2 rule. However all the examples that I see use the example of needing one card to complete your set.

Why we don't consider the fact that I can have two suited cards in hand, and one of the flop cards has the same suite, and then I need both the turn and the river to be the same suit. Why none of the examples that are out there use this?

I know the probability of that is lower that if we just need one card, but how do you calculate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on [Paparazzi](https://poker.stackexchange.com/users/3876/paparazzi)'s answer, you can calculate the odds of a card being dealt next by dividing the number of cards you wish to know the chance of coming by all remaining unknown cards (including those in the deck *and* those in other players' hands). So if you have a suited hand and one card of that suit has come on the flop, the chance of getting another of that suit on the turn is:

```
[# cards of our suit] / [# cards unknown]
= 10 (there are 13 cards of our suit, but 3 have already been dealt) / 47 (there are 52 cards in the deck, but 5 we already know - 3 on the board and 2 in our hand)
= 10 / 47
= 0.21276595... (around 21%)
```

You'll notice that this first part of the calculation confirms the 2-4 rule - we have 10 "outs" to get a 4th card of our suit on the turn, so our odds of doing this are roughly 10 * 2 = 20%.

We then need to calculate the chances of hitting a 5th card of our suit on the river in exactly the same way:

```
[# cards of our suit] / [# cards unknown]
= 9 (there are 13 cards of our suit, but 4 have now been dealt) / 46 (there are 52 cards in the deck, but 6 we already know - 4 on the board and 2 in our hand)
= 9 / 46
= 0.19565217... (around 19.5%)
```

So finally to calculate the probability of *both* events happening (hitting a card of our suit on the turn *and* the river), we multiple these two probabilities together:

```
(10 / 47) * (9 / 46)
= 0.21276595... * 0.19565217...
= 0.04162812... (around 4%)
```

Comment: Thanks :) Is there any quick way to do the multiplication with percentages? Say I am doing the 2-4 rule, so I have 20% and 18%. How do I get to ~4% by multiplying those?

Answer (score 2):

Because the 4-2 rule does apply to runner runner.  There are 2 cards to fill in a set.

Runner runner flush is 10/47 * 9/46 (about 4%).   Not good.

With 2 cards to come a flush draw or open ended straight draw is worth about 1 out.

In this spot if you are getting 2:1 then it is a call.

Comment: Thanks :) I didn't know it was called runner runner.